# how to save all the value in database based on checkboxes checked with jquery using asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a database table in which i have a column called Status which is room status i have used it as Flagged Enum with Cleaning and Inventory Check value,i am using if condition to match the value of Status column in the table with the Enum if it is matching then show that checkbox if value of status in table is 4 and in Enum it is 4 then that respective room require Cleaning if it is 3 then require Inventory Check and so on.

On click of save button i want to get the checked checkboxes value with that respective RoomId which requested for cleaning and Inventory and then pass null value to Status column with that respective RoomId means cleaning and Inventory Check is done for that room then Status should be null no action require for the room

i want to use jquery post method for this

```
                        @if (item.Status == EnumHkStatus.Cleaning)
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" data-cid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input cstatus" />
                            <label>Cleaning</label>
                            <br />
                        }

                        @if (item.Status == EnumHkStatus.InventoryCheck)
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" data-invid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input cstatus" />
                            <label>Inventory Check</label>
                        }

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default insert" data-rid="@item.RoomId">Save</button>

                        $(function () {
    $('.insert').click(function () {
        if ($('cstatus').is(':checked')) {
            var cleaningStatus = $('input[type=checkbox]').val();
        }
        $.post("@Url.Action("SetCleaningStatus", "HouseKeeping")", { id: $(this).data("id"), status: cleaningStatus });
});
```

Controller action method

```
    public ActionResult SetCleaningStatus(int id, int status)
    {
        var RoomSt = db.SingleOrDefault<Room>(id);
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RoomSt.Status = null;
            db.Update(RoomSt);
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show `SetCleaningStatus` controller action with its parameters? Since you want to pass values for all checked checkboxes, you should read `is:checked` selector and pick values from corresponding row or HTML `value` attribute.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i want after clicking on save button if there is value in status column is 4 means it is inventory check that will become null means inventory check for that particular roomid is done